# How to XML mapping using jxls

Tags: java, xml, jxls

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO7Ca.jpg]

Hi.
I use JXLS.
I want to xml mapping cell 'E' (with a numerical expression cell ) when read .xls or xlsx?

How to mapping cell 'E'?

```
<mapping row="3" col="0">testVo.a</mapping>
<mapping row="3" col="1">testVo.b</mapping>
<mapping row="3" col="2">testVo.c</mapping>
<mapping row="3" col="3">testVo.d</mapping>
<mapping row="3" col="4">testVo.e</mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define formula cell in the same way as other cell types.
So the mapping you wrote should work

```
<mapping row="3" col="4">testVo.e</mapping>
```